# Unable to delete Netgear Readyshare namespace folder on Windows C drive

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I used to have an external HDD plugged into the USB port of a Netgear N600. This created a folder on my hard drive called "C:\windows\csc\v2.0.6\namespace\readyshare\USB_Storage".

I am on Windows 10 now. The folder was created when I was on Windows 7.

My own admin account, plus the local administrator account have full access to the "C:\windows\csc\v2.0.6\namespace\readyshare\" folder, but I am unable to delete this folder, receiving the error "you'll need administrator permission to delete this folder".

How do I remove this folder please?

Thanks and regards,
Steve.

Comment: What does the ACL look like?

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. My own admin account has full control over the `readyshare` folder.

Comment: I am not at the specific PC at the moment, but I believe it is either the local admin account, or local admin group also has full control over the `readyshare` folder.